# How to access the Date Last Saved property from a memory stream of excel workbook C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop, memorystream

I have a method that takes a saved .xlsx file as a byteArray input & will out put a datatable of the content with an additional column displaying the last modified date.

I'm unable to retrieve the "Date Last Saved".

I can see the date created, but this changes when the file gets updated & I need to capture this property.

'''

```
public DataTable Transform_closed_XML(byte[] dataBytesArray)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("XLSX Transform");

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(dataBytesArray))
            {

                MemoryStream stream_xlsx = XLSXTransformerHelper.XLSX_Formatter(stream);           


                var workBook = new XLWorkbook(stream_xlsx);

                var pubDate = workBook.Properties.Created; //content created time
                var LastSaved= workBook.Properties.Modified; // this just returns "{01/01/0001 
                 00:00:00}"

                 ...
```

'''

Excel Interop & System.Io work arounds to access this property involve opening an excel file using a file path. I just want to do this directly from the stream.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot get this directly from the byte stream.  Why would you want to?  Use the API instead.

Comment: yes, I don't know that a memory stream would hold that meta data, It doesn't seem appropriate to store that in a header and then you would have to parse it... In windows it is commonly a property of FileInfo object, of which the stream is another property.  Look for the File or FileInfo classes and use those objects to look for LastModifiedDate or something similar.